# Unable to proxy gRPC calls using Charles on android

Tags: android, grpc, charles-proxy

While trying sniffing gRPC traffic I stuck into problem, i see error

```
IO: Stream cancelled by CLIENT
```

after

```
Receiving response body
```

in Charles interface, but I see logs of request/response data in Logcat of android emulator, and this error in Charles debug console:

```
2022/07/13 16:52:02 FINE     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Frame                            Sending #1575100373 [my-host.ru] CLIENT frame: HEADERS 5
2022/07/13 16:52:02 INFO     com.xk72.proxy.http2.Http2ProxyHandler.FrameHandler   #1575100373 [my-host.ru] SERVER frame handler runtime error
2022/07/13 16:52:02 java.lang.IllegalStateException
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at com.xk72.proxy.http2.f.a(Unknown Source)
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at com.xk72.proxy.http2.A.a(Unknown Source)
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at com.xk72.proxy.http2.q.run(Unknown Source)
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at com.xk72.util.d.run(Unknown Source)
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
2022/07/13 16:52:02     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

At another side i see some readable parts of response in Contents tab in Charles, but request fails.

Charles v4.6.2

Android sdks for protos:

```
grpc_version = '1.45.1'
api 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.12.0'
api 'com.google.api.grpc:googleapis-common-protos:0.0.3'
api "io.grpc:grpc-netty:$grpc_version"
api "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpc_version"
api "io.grpc:grpc-android:$grpc_version"
api "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpc_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Mediator](https://github.com/ButterCam/Mediator) is a Cross-platform GUI gRPC debugging proxy like Charles but design for gRPC.

You can dump all gRPC requests without any configuration.

Mediator can render the binary message into a JSON tree, when you have the API schema.

It support decode gRPC/TLS, but you should download and install the Mediator Root Certificate to your device like Charles do.